# TreeView - Jtree (NetBeans) Como adicionar uma descrição a um nó selecionado

Tags: java, netbeans, jtree, treeview

Estou fazendo um treeview simples no NetBeans e gostaria de saber como faço para adicionar uma descrição para um determinado nó selecionado, por meio de um botão que possui uma função que associará a um lable.

[image: treeview]

[image: o que eu quero implementar]

o código para o botão ">>" que irá inserir a descrição está assim:

```
private void add2ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                     
   lTree2.setText(tf2.getText());
}
```

obviamente não faz o que pretendo, só coloquei para ilustrar o que eu quero saber.

Comment: Não entendi muito bem sua pergunta. Você deseja substituir o 'aaa' por 'bbb'? Você tem um model cuidando dos itens da sua JTree?